# Incrementing Dictionary Values Inside Comprehensions

Tags: python

Often something like the following seems like a good idea.  Why does it not work?  Is a for loop the best way to fix it?

```
D = {'A':7,'B':10}

{D['B']+=i for i in range(3)}
```

`+=i` causes an error.

Is this the "python" fix?

```
for i in range(3):
    D['B'] += 1
```

Comment: What you wrote is a set comprehension BTW. It does not work because it expects an expression to the left of `for` but `a += b` is a statement, not an expression.

Comment: Oops, you aren't even trying to do what I thought (incrementing all dictionary values by the same amount), so the duplicate is not 100% accurate. But it makes me wonder: why do you want to write any kind of loop (explicit or a comprehension) at all?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use comprehensions (list, set, or dictionary) for their side-effects, but rather to create a *new* list/set/dictionary. The loop is the correct tool for modifying an existing list/set/dictionary.

However, in this case, why not simply write the following?

```
D['B'] += 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary comprehension can't (really it can, but it shouldn't; the dictionary comprehension is a way of 'assembling' a new thing, not changing an existing one) modify an existing thing in this way; it wants to be made up of expressions it can *evaluate*, whereas you have code you want to *execute*. Your suggestion at the bottom is totally fine. :)

If you want to write the dictionary comprehension, you would need to do:

```
{k: v + i for i, (k, v) in enumerate(D.items())}
```

`D.items()` gets the items of the dictionary and `enumerate` let's you count them, like the index of your `for` loop.